# How to read a list of parquet files from S3 as a pandas dataframe using pyarrow?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boto3, pyarrow

I have a hacky way of achieving this using `boto3` (1.4.4), `pyarrow` (0.4.1) and `pandas` (0.20.3).

First, I can read a single parquet file locally like this:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

path = 'parquet/part-r-00000-1e638be4-e31f-498a-a359-47d017a0059c.gz.parquet'
table = pq.read_table(path)
df = table.to_pandas()
```

I can also read a directory of parquet files locally like this:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('parquet/')
table = dataset.read()
df = table.to_pandas()
```

Both work like a charm. Now I want to achieve the same remotely with files stored in a S3 bucket. I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('s3n://dsn/to/my/bucket')
```

But it does not:

`OSError: Passed non-file path: s3n://dsn/to/my/bucket`

After reading [pyarrow's documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/) thoroughly, this does not seem possible [at the moment](http://markmail.org/message/uo4kvzrt6ce6yruw). So I came out with the following solution:

Reading a single file from S3 and getting a pandas dataframe:

```
import io
import boto3
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

buffer = io.BytesIO()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3.Object('bucket-name', 'key/to/parquet/file.gz.parquet')
s3_object.download_fileobj(buffer)
table = pq.read_table(buffer)
df = table.to_pandas()
```

And here my hacky, not-so-optimized, solution to create a pandas dataframe from a S3 folder path:

```
import io
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

bucket_name = 'bucket-name'
def download_s3_parquet_file(s3, bucket, key):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    s3.Object(bucket, key).download_fileobj(buffer)
    return buffer

client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
objects_dict = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix='my/folder/prefix')
s3_keys = [item['Key'] for item in objects_dict['Contents'] if item['Key'].endswith('.parquet')]
buffers = [download_s3_parquet_file(s3, bucket_name, key) for key in s3_keys]
dfs = [pq.read_table(buffer).to_pandas() for buffer in buffers]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Maybe some kind of connector for pandas using pyarrow? I would like to avoid using `pyspark`, but if there is no other solution, then I would take it.

Comment: Have you consider to read them with dask? I'm able to do the same in two lines.

Comment: Got your hacky solution working only after filtering to files with size > 0:
`dfs = [pq.read_table(buffer).to_pandas() for buffer in buffers if len(buffer.getvalue()) > 0]`. Thanks! Unfortunately the answers here don't quite address this issue.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should use the `s3fs` module as proposed by [yjk21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284315/yjk21). However as result of calling ParquetDataset you'll get a pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset object. To get the Pandas DataFrame you'll rather want to apply `.read_pandas().to_pandas()` to it:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

pandas_dataframe = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://your-bucket/', filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

Comment: got : ValueError: Found files in an intermediate directory . Any idea?

Comment: @Mithril Your error message is unfortunatelly truncated, so I can't see the directory mentioned. However one could make a guess. Indeed, when the partitioned parquet files are stored to S3, they are usually first written to "_temporary" directory. If this directory not empty then it is a clear sign, that S3-location contains incomplete (broken) data.

Comment: What happens when you do this? Does it stream or does it copied to local? If I open a 10GB file 2x does it download it 2x? What if I open 10GB file with only 5GB local storage, does it stream or download it all?

Comment: When I specify the key where all my parquet files reside I get `ArrowIOError: Invalid Parquet file size is 0 bytes`. When I explicitly specify the parquet file, it works. i use s3fs == 0.3.5 and pyarrow == 0.15.0. @vak any idea why I cannot read all the parquet files in the s3 key like you did?

Comment: @VincentClaes trailing slash?

Comment: hmm that gives me `OSError: Unrecognized filesystem: <class 'fs_s3fs._s3fs.S3FS'>`

Comment: I get `OSError: Passed non-file path: s3a://bucket/path/to/my/part_files.parquet/`

Comment: Is it possible to read parquet in AWS S3 using pq.ParquetFile() ? if yes, what are pros and cons of using it over pq.ParquetDataset()

Answer (score 40):

Thanks! Your question actually tell me a lot. This is how I do it now with `pandas` (0.21.1), which will call `pyarrow`, and `boto3` (1.3.1).

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

# Read single parquet file from S3
def pd_read_s3_parquet(key, bucket, s3_client=None, **args):
    if s3_client is None:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), **args)

# Read multiple parquets from a folder on S3 generated by spark
def pd_read_s3_multiple_parquets(filepath, bucket, s3=None, 
                                 s3_client=None, verbose=False, **args):
    if not filepath.endswith('/'):
        filepath = filepath + '/'  # Add '/' to the end
    if s3_client is None:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    if s3 is None:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_keys = [item.key for item in s3.Bucket(bucket).objects.filter(Prefix=filepath)
               if item.key.endswith('.parquet')]
    if not s3_keys:
        print('No parquet found in', bucket, filepath)
    elif verbose:
        print('Load parquets:')
        for p in s3_keys: 
            print(p)
    dfs = [pd_read_s3_parquet(key, bucket=bucket, s3_client=s3_client, **args) 
           for key in s3_keys]
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Then you can read multiple parquets under a folder from S3 by

```
df = pd_read_s3_multiple_parquets('path/to/folder', 'my_bucket')
```

(One can simplify this code a lot I guess.)

Answer (score 17):

Provided you have the right package setup

```sh
$ pip install pandas==1.1.0 pyarrow==1.0.0 s3fs==0.4.2
```

and your AWS shared [config and credentials files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/file-location.html) [configured appropriately](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/file-format.html)

you can use `pandas` right away:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet("s3://bucket/key.parquet")
```

---

In case of having multiple AWS [profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) you may also need to set

```sh
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=profile_under_which_the_bucket_is_accessible
```

so you can access your bucket.

Comment: Thanks! This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: Right, the new pandas can read s3 path directly now. Though somehow, it is much slower than the `io.BytesIO` methods when I tried it.

Comment: `Install s3fs to access S3`

Comment: cant get this to work with poetry the dependencies for s3fs to botocore are pinned

Answer (score 15):

It can be done using boto3 as well without the use of pyarrow

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

# Read the parquet file
buffer = io.BytesIO()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')
object.download_fileobj(buffer)
df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 's3.Object' object has no attribute 'download_fileobj'`.

Comment: I think the poster means 'without the use of s3fs', anyway this is a great answer if you need the BytesIO buffer.

Answer (score 13):

Probably the easiest way to read parquet data on the cloud into dataframes is to use [dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) in this way:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/path/to/data-*.parq')
```

`dask.dataframe` can [read from Google Cloud Storage, Amazon S3, Hadoop file system and more](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html#remote-data)!

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that you can't distribute on a cluster in case you need.

Comment: My issue is that I get an error reading too many files. Could it be dask can't handle it and therefore need to resort to another solution?

Comment: I have 0-byte _SUCCESS header files in my directory of parquet files. Tried excluding them in the glob with: `dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/test.parquet/[!_]*')` but resulted in `IndexError: list index out of range`. Either because no matches, or some 0-size files.

Comment: `pip install dask[dataframe]`

Answer (score 10):

If you are open to also use [AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler).

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://...")
```

Comment: I dont know why , but it takes a lot of time to read the data ? like 6 sec for only 1.3 mb of dataset?

Comment: Your example will expect one parquet file. You need to set the parameter `dataset = True` to read a list of parquet files.

Comment: for some reason, I am getting the timeout error.
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://......../",
                            path_suffix = ".snappy.parquet",
                            dataset=True)
"errorMessage": "................................ Task timed out after 3.14 seconds"

any inputs...

Answer (score 4):

You can use s3fs from dask which implements a filesystem interface for s3. Then you can use the filesystem argument of ParquetDataset like so:

```
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('s3n://dsn/to/my/bucket', filesystem=s3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pre-signed URLs

```
s3 =s3fs.S3FileSystem(key='your_key',secret='your_secret',client_kwargs={"endpoint_url":'your_end_point'})

df = dd.read_parquet(s3.url('your_bucket' + 'your_filepath',expires=3600,client_method='get_object'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the @oya163 solution and it works but after little bit change

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd

# Read the parquet file
buffer = io.BytesIO()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='123',aws_secret_access_key= '456')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name','myoutput.parquet')
object.download_fileobj(buffer)
df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).