# pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Invalid Parquet file size is 0 bytes

Tags: python, boto3, pyarrow

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809552/2071807), reading a list of files from an S3 bucket into a pyarrow table.

If I specify the filename I can do:

```
from pyarrow.parquet import ParquetDataset
import s3fs
dataset = ParquetDataset(
    "s3://path/to/file/myfile.snappy.parquet",
    filesystem=s3fs.S3FileSystem(),
)
```

And everything works as expected. However if I do:

```
dataset = ParquetDataset(
    "s3://path/to/file",
    filesystem=s3fs.S3FileSystem(),
)
```

I get:

```
pyarrow/_parquet.pyx:1036: in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.open                                                                                                                                                                                                              
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Invalid Parquet file size is 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me because of empty "success" files that were at the same S3 prefix as my parquet files. I resolved this by first listing out the parquet files and selecting only those with names ending in ".parquet":

```py
from pyarrow.parquet import ParquetDataset
import s3fs

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

paths = [path for path in s3.ls("s3://path/to/file/") if path.endswith(".parquet")]

dataset = ParquetDataset(paths, filesystem=s3)
```

Comment: this is the right answer!

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer has something to do with this, from the [Apache Arrow docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-from-partitioned-datasets):

> The ParquetDataset class accepts either a directory name or a list or file paths, and can discover and infer some common partition structures, such as those produced by Hive:
>
> ```
> dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('dataset_name/')
> table = dataset.read()
> ```

So I think the automatic discovery of filenames only works if the files you're trying to get hold of are partitioned by, e.g. Hive.