# getting TypeError when using write_pandas method

Tags: pandas, snowflake-connector

Using solutions from this question: [How to read a list of parquet files from S3 as a pandas dataframe using pyarrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043554/how-to-read-a-list-of-parquet-files-from-s3-as-a-pandas-dataframe-using-pyarrow/48809552#48809552), I am importing the following in order to copy data from an s3 bucket to a snowflake table:

```
    from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
```

When I try to use the method "write_pandas" I get the error:

```
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'
```

Here's my code:

```
    conn = snow.connect(
        user="ll", 
        password="zzz",
        account="account",
        role="role",
        warehouse="WAREHOUSE",
        database="db",
        schema="C")

    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, key = 'AKI', secret = 'zzz')  
    pandas_dataframe = pq.ParquetDataset('s3://bucket/folder2/File.snappy.parquet', 
    filesystem=s3).read_pandas().to_pandas()


    write_pandas(conn, pandas_dataframe, "DATATABLE")
```

What do I need to do to add this required argument? Or is there a different solution?

Comment: is your connection object conn? if so, use conn=conn or maybe change your connection object to cxn. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#write_pandas

Comment: did you figure it out?