# Read parquet files from S3 bucket in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to read parquet files from an AWS S3 bucket in a for loop.

Here's my code (that doesn't work):

```
session = boto3.Session(
                    aws_access_key_id=key,
                    aws_secret_access_key=secret,
                    region_name=region_name)
                    
s3 = session.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder_path):

    response = obj.get()

    df = pd.read_parquet(response['Body'])
    
    # some data processing
```

It prints the following errors:
`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` and `ArrowInvalid: Called Open() on an uninitialized FileSource`.

What should I fix here?

Comment: What do you mean by `that doesn't work`?

Comment: It doesn't read the files.

Comment: Does it give any specific error?

Comment: Nothing... Note that with CSV files, it does work.

Comment: Sorry, now I can see an error. It prints: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` and `ArrowInvalid: Called Open() on an uninitialized FileSource`.

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Have you tried printing the contents of `response` or `response['Body']` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.read_parquet()` expects a a reference to the file to read, not the file contents itself as you provide it.

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html):

> **path : str, path object or file-like object**
>
> String, path object (implementing `os.PathLike[str]`), or file-like object implementing a binary `read()` function. The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, gs, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. A local file could be: `file://localhost/path/to/table.parquet`. A file URL can also be a path to a directory that contains multiple partitioned parquet files. Both pyarrow and fastparquet support paths to directories as well as file URLs. A directory path could be: `file://localhost/path/to/tables` or `s3://bucket/partition_dir`.

As you can see you can provide an S3-url as path, so the least intrusive change to make it work would probably be this:

```py
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder_path):
     obj_url = f"s3://{obj.bucket_name}/{obj.key}"
     df = pd.read_parquet(obj_url)
```

Alternatively "[How to read a list of parquet files from S3 as a pandas dataframe using pyarrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043554/how-to-read-a-list-of-parquet-files-from-s3-as-a-pandas-dataframe-using-pyarrow)" lists several other solutions.