# How to show user schema in a Parquet file using DuckDB?

Tags: parquet, database-metadata, duckdb

I am trying to use DuckDB to show the user-created schema that I have written into a Parquet file.  I can demonstrate in Python (using the code example at [Get schema of parquet file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567081/get-schema-of-parquet-file-in-python)) that the schema is as I desire, but cannot seem to find a way in DuckDB to get this information.

Neither of the following queries reports the user-created schema

```sql
select * from parquet_schema('FileWithMetadata.parquet')
```

```sql
select * from parquet_metadata('FileWithMetadata.parquet')
```

---

**update**:

Here is the code snippet that creates the metadata in the Parquet file where a is a Pandas dataframe of daily basin flows for a number of different simulations:

```py
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(a)
my_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field("Flow", "float", True, metadata={"data":"flow in mm per day"}),
    pa.field("DayIndex", "int64", False, metadata={"data":"index of days"}),
    pa.field("BasinIndex", "string", True, metadata={"data":"flow in mm per day"}),
    pa.field("Simulation", "int64", True, metadata={"data":"simulation number"})
    ],

    metadata={"info":"long format basin flows"})

t2 = table.cast(my_schema)
pq.write_table(t2, 'SHALongWithMetadata1.parquet')
```

and the code to read it back is:

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
pfile = pq.read_table("C:\Projects\CSDP\PythonCSDP\Parquet\SHALongWithMetadata1.parquet")
print("Column names: {}".format(pfile.column_names))
print("Schema: {}".format(pfile.schema))
```

and this yields as output :

```py
Column names: ['Flow', 'DayIndex', 'BasinIndex', 'Simulation']
Schema: Flow: float
  -- field metadata --
  data: 'flow in mm per day'
DayIndex: int64 not null
  -- field metadata --
  data: 'index of days'
BasinIndex: string
  -- field metadata --
  data: 'flow in mm per day'
Simulation: int64
  -- field metadata --
  data: 'simulation number'
-- schema metadata --
info: 'long format basin flows'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM parquet_schema('FileWithMetadata.parquet')` should return the DuckDB SQL schema.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DESCRIBE](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet/metadata#parquet-schema) keyword:

```
DESCRIBE
SELECT *
FROM 'FileWithMetadata.parquet';

DESCRIBE TABLE
'FileWithMetadata.parquet';
```

Table function `parquet_metadata` repeats the same information for each row group in the Parquet file, so use `SELECT DISTINCT` to report only one set of unique column names and types:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  path_in_schema,
  type 
FROM parquet_metadata('FileWithMetadata.parquet');
```

Comment: Sorry does not work, I had tried that previously, just yields column name, type, null, key, and default fields:                       Flow FLOAT YES   
                DayIndex BIGINT YES   
                BasinIndex VARCHAR YES   
                Simulation BIGINT YES

Comment: What kind of schema do you want?  DuckDB reports the SQL schema.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the input user-defined metadata creation in Python, the script to read it back, and the results.  This is to allow the Parquet file to be self-describing, similar to netcdf and HDF5 files.